# Cannot execute .exe file on debugging project in visual studio 2022 mac

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Getting "Cannot execute '.exe' file" when trying to debug (using PLAY button) on visual studio 2022 for mac.

[VS Project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWsY0.png)

Due to this, i am not able to debug my code. Breakpoints doesn't work as soon as project is built.

Comment: make sure the app is killed and is not open in the background of your mac

Comment: I'm not familiar with VS, but... is it trying to produce a Windows executable rather than one for macOS? The reason I ask is that the .exe extension isn't generally used for macOS (or unix or linux) executables; it's mostly used for Windows executables.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I running VS 2022 Mac and am having the exact same issue. It just says, "Cannot execute /path/to/file/net6.0/whatever.exe"

Oddly, it appears to run fine in JetBrains Rider, but I'd prefer to stick with Visual Studio since it's what everyone else in the company is using (and the Rider interface is confusing).